Multiple IF statements in DAX relative to current date - syntax
I need help with the syntax for a multiple if statement in DAX
I have data in table
'All Occupational Competences (2) Sig Removed'
and
Column
'Emp Comp Valid Until'
I want to set a measure that tells us (my pseudo code below)
If 'Emp Comp Valid Until' <Today, "Expired",
If 'Emp Comp Valid Until' Between Today And Today +28, "1 Pd",
If 'Emp Comp Valid Until' Between Today +28 And Today +56, "2 Pds",
If 'Emp Comp Valid Until' Between Today +56 And Today +84, "3 Pds",
)

Any help welcome - thanks in advance !

This is the equivalent DAX code:
Switch(True()
    , [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < Today(), "Expired"
    , [Emp Comp Valid Unit] >= Today() && [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < Today() + 28, "1 Pd"
    , [Emp Comp Valid Unit] >= Today() + 28 && [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < Today() + 56, "2 Pds"
    , [Emp Comp Valid Unit] >= Today() + 56 && [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < Today() + 84, "3 Pds"
    )


SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < TODAY(), "Expired",
    [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < TODAY() + 28, "1 Pd",
    [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < TODAY() + 56, "2 Pds",
    [Emp Comp Valid Unit] < TODAY() + 84, "3 Pds",
    "Other"
)

